# Check date is Greater using Calendar control in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm having a situation where i'm having a Calendar control in my page and when user selects a date it should check whether date selected is greater than today's date.

I tried a lot and Googled it as well, but in every place they are taking value using a textbox and i want the same to be done with a Calendar control.

Comment: Calendar control does not provide validation functionality. What makes you think it does though? To validate the date, use ASP.NET validators or custom code, as you found out already.

Comment: You took my post in a wrong sense, i want to use Validations and validate the selected date, and tried with CompareValidator and it's not working

Comment: Oh, so you are ok with using built-in validators, but do not want to use code behind? That makes sense, although that's still a strange requirement. You should also post what you have tried to show that you actually took an effort to resolve the issue yourself

Comment: I trie something like this with CompareValidator
<asp:comparevalidator ID="cvDate" runat="server" 
                    errormessage="The date must be greater than today"
                    controltovalidate="cDate" type="Date" 
                    valuetocompare="<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>" />

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, you actually don't need any C# code to get this done! All you need is some extenders and validators on your date textbox. So let's say I had two textboxes -- one named txtStartDt and one named txtEndDate; this is how the extensions for them would be placed:

```
// Start Date
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDt" runat="server" CssClass="textboxint" /> // the main control itself
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calStartDt" runat="server" PopupPosition="BottomRight" 
 TargetControlID="txtStartDt" /> // allows the control to behave like a calendar picker
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CVStartDt" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="LessThan"
 ErrorMessage="Start Date must come before the End Date" ValidationGroup="ReportDate"
 ControlToValidate="txtStartDt" ControlToCompare="txtEndDt" Display="None" /> // THIS is the main solution to your problem
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEStartDt" runat="server" TargetControlID="CVStartDt"
 HighlightCssClass="valCalloutint" /> // Checks that the CV is working correctly
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVStartDt" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartDt"
 Display="None" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" ValidationGroup="ReportDate" /> // ensures a value was added to the textbox
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEreqStartDt" runat="server" TargetControlID="RFVStartDt"
HighlightCssClass="valCalloutint" PopupPosition="BottomRight" /> // Checks that the RFV is working correctly

// End Date
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDt" runat="server" CssClass="textboxint" />
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calEndDt" runat="server" PopupPosition="BottomRight" TargetControlID="txtEndDt" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CVEndDt" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThan"
 ErrorMessage="End Date must come after the Start Date" ValidationGroup="ReportDate"
 ControlToValidate="txtEndDt" ControlToCompare="txtStartDt" Display="None" />
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEEndDt" runat="server" TargetControlID="CVEndDt"
 HighlightCssClass="valCalloutint" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVEndDt" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEndDt"
 Display="None" ErrorMessage="End Date is required" ValidationGroup="ReportDate" />
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEreqEndDt" runat="server" TargetControlID="RFVEndDt"
 HighlightCssClass="valCalloutint" PopupPosition="BottomRight" />
```

Note that the extra ValidatorCalloutExtender tools are not redundant, but actually allows the program to prevent the user from entering an empty value for one of the textboxes.
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The calendar control should have a property called [SelectedDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can compare this property with any other DateTime property. The code snippet below will check if the SelectedDate is greater than today.

```
if (Calendar.SelectedDate > DateTime.Now())
{

}
```